# Why only one of these 2 smilar macros to create bordures works?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table without borders. I want to create borders for all the cells where the titles of the rows are.

I am making that with a macro.

```
Sub BorderTable()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = RangeTitelsAxisX
    r.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'a1
    r.Borders.Weight = xlMedium        'a2
End sub
```

This macro  works. But the following macro fails with this error

> "Runtime Error 424 'Object Required'"

```
Sub BorderTable()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = RangeTitelsAxisX
    BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge (r) 'b
End Sub
```

And for me this 2 macros are equivalent. ( I only replace 21, a2 by b and you can see above that b= a1, a2

```
Private Sub BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge(r As Range)
    r.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    r.Borders.Weight = xlMedium 'xlThick
End Sub



Function RangeTitelsAxisX() As Range
    Range("B3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set RangeTitelsAxisX = Selection
End Function
```

Why the second way to do the macro doesn't work?

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge r`. Or alternatively, `BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge r:=r`.

Comment: `Call BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge(r)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge (r)
```

That's invoking `BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge`, but the argument being passed is not an object.

`(r)` as an argument means "let-coerce `r` into a value, then pass that value to the invoked procedure" - no impact in this particular case, but note that this effectively pases the value `ByVal`, since the calling code isn't holding a reference (a local variable) to the result of that expression.

Note the space between `BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge` and `(r)`: that's the VBE telling you the parentheses are part of the *argument*, not the procedure call (i.e. they're not delimiting a comma-separated list of arguments)

This would be a compile-time syntax error:

```
BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge (r, 42)
```

Because the expression `(r, 42)` can't be evaluated, it means nothing to VBA.

`r` being a `Range` object, let-coercion is implicitly invoking its hidden `[_Default]` member, which in this case returns a 2D variant array - `BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge` is receiving that 2D variant array and says "dude I asked for an object reference", hence the "object required" error.

So, to fix the error, simply remove the parentheses:

```
 BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge r
```

Alternatively, introduce a `Call` keyword (Rubberduck will [flag it as obsolete](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ObsoleteCallStatement) and [offer to cleanly remove it](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/QuickFixInfo/RemoveExplicitCallStatement)):

```
 Call BoldBorderAllCellOfRAnge(r)
```

Note that the VBE will no longer force a whitespace between the procedure name and the `(` opening parenthesis now, and that means the `(...)` is now delimiting an arguments list, rather than forcing the evaluation of an expression.

---

About this function:

> ```
> Function RangeTitelsAxisX() As Range
>     Range("B3").Select
>     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
>     Set RangeTitelsAxisX = Selection
> End Function
> ```

Consider avoiding `Range.Select` whenever possible. This should be equivalent, and much more efficient - note that the function is [implicitly public](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitPublicMember), but should be private if it's only ever invoked by other procedures in the same module.

Also, the unqualified `Range` call is [implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) if that code is written anywhere other than in a worksheet module's code-behind:

```
Private Function RangeTitelsAxisX() As Range
    Set RangeTitelsAxisX = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").End(xlDown)
End Function
```

If the code is written in a worksheet module, you'll want it like this:

```
Private Function RangeTitelsAxisX() As Range
    Set RangeTitelsAxisX = Me.Range("B3").End(xlDown)
End Function
```

Always qualify `Range` calls with a proper `Worksheet` object: you'll avoid lots of bugs.

Comment: "dude I asked for an object reference" - lol. Should be the TL;DR, though I guess the answer isn't that long.

Comment: The tl;dr was your comment on the OP ;-)